# ODB PL/SQL API for a created View?

Tags: database, oracle, api, view

For a given Oracle Database (ODB) 12c table you have the chance to create a CRUD-style API using JDeveloper or SQL Developer by right clicking on it.

Before considering creating a query for several tables that are related to each other with a primary key, I want to know if it is possible to create an API if I create a view for these tables? Particularly the `Insert`?

The database normalization is very strict from the side of our customer.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to just try it and see what happens?

Comment: hi, wanted to ask first, Im finishing my datamodel and havent try it yet

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what kind of "API" you'd be creating. What would this API look like? How would you use it? What value would it provide? What problems would using it cause? Thanks.

Comment: hi Im referring to the following kind of API generated by JDeveloper SQL Developer like the one shown on the link below http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/05/an-oracle-designer-feature-generating-table-apis-with-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: The answer is NO, You cannot have a table API from a view with Jdeveloper or SQL Developer by right click on it .

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, You cannot have a table API from a view with Jdeveloper or SQL Developer by right click on i